# Java getUserObject() return string instead of userobject

Tags: java, jtree

After I created a node I'd like to get a MyNodeUserObject so I can call the getFlops() method later. But I can't cast the userobject to MyNodeUserObject.

Creating the node:

```
MyNodeUserObject userObject = new MyNodeUserObject("aaa","AA-10");

DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(userObject);


public static void visitAllNodes(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, JTree tree) {
    //java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to MyNodeUserObject
    MyNodeUserObject nodeInfo = (MyNodeUserObject) node.getUserObject();
```

MyNodeUserObject.class

```
public final class MyNodeUserObject{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final String flops;
    private final String nodeName;

    public MyNodeUserObject(String nodeName, String flops) {
        this.flops = flops;
        this.nodeName = nodeName;
    }

    public String getFlops() {
        return flops;
    }

    public String getNodeName() {
        return nodeName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nodeName;
    }
```

**Content of tree.txt:**
Node name;IsFolder(true/false);Parent;Flops
my ranges;true; ;
a;false;my ranges;AA,AKs,AKo
b;false;my ranges;66,55,44,33,22
c;false;my ranges;JJ,TT,99,88

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question with a [MCVE]. Are you sure this is the same instance of `DefaultMutableTreeNode` and that nothing else calls `setUserObject` on it in between?

Comment: How do you build your tree? Can you show us the code?

Comment: The tree is builded from a txt file. Here is the full code: https:// paste.ofcode.org/9QnFLUQayyRY79ksz2u7ij

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code you linked in a comment, the root node of your tree actually does contain a `String` ("<html><b>Ranges</b></html>") as its `userObject`.

Given that, your options are

- Replace the root node with a node around `MyNodeUserObject`; this probably necessitates some changes to that class to handle the root node correctly
- Add a special case in the `visitAllNodes` method (checking for `instanceof MyNodeUserObject`, for example)
- Make sure `visitAllNodes` is not called with the root node